# Jquery datatable has some gap between the header and the body part

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am working with Jquery datatable. My problem is that the Jquery datatable has some gap between the header and the body part.I have initialized the datatable as below:

```
var table = $('#claimListTable').DataTable({
            "bSort": false,
            "scrollY": 720, // inconsistent IE7/other
            "scrollX": true,
            "searching": false,
            "paging": false,
            "info": false,
            "fnRowCallback": function( nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex ) {
                // highlight groups of 3 rows
                var odd = Math.floor(iDisplayIndex / 3) % 2;
                var rowClass = odd == 1 ? "odd" : "even";
                $(nRow).attr("class", rowClass);
                return nRow;
            }

        });
        $("thead th").css({"border-bottom":"none","padding": "5px 0px"});

        $("#claimListTable.dataTable thead th").css({"border-bottom":"none",
            "padding": "5px 0px"});
        $("#claimListTable.dataTable tbody td").css({"border-bottom":"none",
            "padding": "5px 0px"});
        $("#claimListTable.dataTable tbody tr").css({"cursor": "default"});
        $("div .dataTables_scrollBody").css({"overflow-x": "auto",
            "overflow-y": "auto",
            "border-bottom": "none"});

    }

[![enter image description here][1]][1]There is some gap between the header part and the body part after the initialization of the datatable.
```

When I make `<thead>` part of the table `claimListTable` as `display:none` after initialization using developer tools, the gap area is vanishing. But I don't know how to do this after the table initialization using jquery. If at all if there is any other workaround, that would also be fine.

```
I could not able to create the working fiddle as it has some dependencies, but I created a sample fiddle to get some idea
```

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EjFtX/59/)

[image]

Comment: after visited jsFiddle I found the extra space is because of thead

Comment: Yes, but I need that to display the table properly. Is there any workaround to get rid of that?

Comment: @Ibrahim shaikh, How can I make that `thead ` as `display:none' after loading the table?

Comment: @Ashok.N `display:none` will create another problem. See my (revised) answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of hiding the row that is creating the gap you must *collapse* it:

```
table#claimListTable thead {
    visibility: collapse;
}
```

The reason why you cannot simply hide it is because contains some content to ensure that the table's columns remain aligned with the *header* table above it.

Comment: Super!! You saved my day dude. Thanks much!! +1 for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Add below css and you are done...

```
table#claimListTable>thead {
    display: none;
}
```

See updated fiddle...

http://jsfiddle.net/EjFtX/60/

Comment: Wow! super dude! it worked perfectly! You saved my time!! +1 for that..

Comment: But the header alignment is slightly misaligned with your change. Can you also help me on that?

Comment: header is as it is, i checked. This code did not affected anything else...

Comment: I am sorry..The column values are misaligned. Especially the second column values.

Comment: The header is placed there deliberately to make both tables align properly. You hide it you disturb the alignment.

Comment: @ Salman A, If I don't hide it, the gap is shown. How to overcome this now?

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I have as my gap between head and body.
[My gap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RSnLv.png)

Upon viewing the element, I had a margin-bottom: 20px
It was based on my table element, from a bootstrap.min.css style.

Then I added

```
style="margin-bottom: 0px"
```

to my table element and it removed the gap.